# Cannot Retrieve User Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So basically I am trying to create a more interactive date picker. I am doing this by first allowing the user to enter their name. Once they hit submit, it should now say... Hello "the user's name".

But for some reason the if else statement I have used will not work. I have looked over my code and it seems correct but the user input wont print out.It should also check if the input is a string, it will continue. If it is anything but a string, like a number, it will output onto the screen... "You must tell us your name to move on!". How do I use an if else statement on anything the user enters? Can someone look through my code and help me out? I have looked all around and could find nothing along these lines. Maybe this is a duplicate or I have gone about this entirely incorrectly, I'm just not sure. Thank you for your help. Suggestions to make this better would be highly appreciated as well! :)

THE HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Going On Vacation!</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>Heading Somewhere?</h1>
    <div id="main">
    <h2>What is your name?</h2>
        <input id="name" type= "text" placeholder="  Tell us!">

        <button id ="submit">Submit!</button>
    </div>

        <p id="user"></p>
        <p id="when"></p>
        <input id="date" placeholder="Choose your departure!">
        <p id="error1"></p>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

THE JAVASCRIPT:

```
$('#date').hide();

function userName(){
var user_name = $('#name').val();
$('#submit').click(function(){
 if(typeof user_name === 'string'){
     $('#main').hide('slow');
         document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "Hello " + user_name + "!";
         $('#user').css("margin-left", "641px");
         $('#when').css("margin-left", "598px");
         document.getElementById("when").innerHTML = "When are you leaving?";
         $('#date').show();
         $('#date').datepicker();
     } else {
         document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "You must tell us your name to move on!"; 
     }
   });
 };


$(document).ready(userName);
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @FrEaKmAn How do I use if else statements with anything the user inputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not work because you are reading the username field before the user fills it in!

```
var user_name = $('#name').val();
```

That line needs to be INSIDE the submit method.

Second the typeof check makes no sense. You want to be checking the length.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
    var user_name = $.trim($('#name').val());
    if(user_name.length>0){
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! But the user can still continue if they input a number even though I used  if(typeof user_name === 'string') and the else statement, why?

Comment: BECAUSE it is a string.... "3" is a string...That is NOT a number. val() gives a string, it does not convert the input to the type.

Comment: Ohh okay I understand, I was not thinking, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

user_name is outside the scope. Just move the user declaration var to inside submit event:

```
function userName(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
      var user_name = $('#name').val();
     if(typeof user_name === 'string'){
         $('#main').hide('slow');
             document.getElementById("user").innerHTML = "Hello " + user_name + "!";
             $('#user').css("margin-left", "641px");
             $('#when').css("margin-left", "598px");
             document.getElementById("when").innerHTML = "When are you leaving?";
             $('#date').show();
             $('#date').datepicker();
         } else {
             document.getElementById("error1").innerHTML = "You must tell us your name to move   on!"; 
        }
      });
    };
```

if you don't want to jQuery look for the object in DOM every time the user clicks on submit. You can find the object outside the scope, but the value must be retrieved inside the submit event. Example:

```
...
 var userObj = $('#name');
 $('#submit').click(function(){
          var user_name = userObj.val();
 ...
```

Comment: Because jQuery val() will always return a string. You should use your own way to check it the user entered a number.